# How to invoke python script from power bi?

Tags: python, powerbi

How can I invoke a python script in visual studio code from Power BI and run a function and get some output and print it somewhere in  a text box in power BI dashboard?

Is it possible in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported.

Power BI supports limited Python functionality in Power Query and within the Power BI data model, but there is no current support for injecting scripts from VS Code.